# Goodness of fit always being zero despite taking random data?

Tags: python-3.x, chi-squared

I'm trying to write code that generates random data and computes goodness of fit but I'm not understanding why the chi-squared test is always zero, may I have a fix for this ? For an attempted fix I tried playing around with different types to see if I get any resulting changes in the initial output, also I've tried changing the parameters to the loop in question.

```
from scipy import stats
import math
import random
import numpy 
import scipy 
import numpy as np

def Linear_Chi2_Generate(observed_values = [], expected_values = []):
    #===============================================================#
    #            !!!!!!! Generation of Data  !!!!!!!!!!             #
    #===============================================================#

    for i in range(0,12):
        a = random.randint(-10,10)
        b = random.randint(-10,10)
        y = a * (b + i)
        observed_values.append(y)


    #######################################################################################
    #                               !!! Array Setup !!!!                                  #
    #              ***Had the Array types converted to floats before computing Chi2***    #
    #                                                                                     #
    #######################################################################################
    t_s = 0
    o_v = np.array(observed_values)
    e_v = np.array(expected_values)
    o_v_f = o_v.astype(float)
    e_v_f = o_v.astype(float)
    z_o_e_v_f = zip(o_v.astype(float), e_v.astype(float))

    ######################################################################################
    for i in z_o_e_v_f:
        t_s += [((o_v_f)-(e_v_f))]**2/(e_v_f) # Computs the Chi2 Stat !
    ######################################################################################
    print("Observed Values ", o_v_f)
    print("Expected Values" , e_v_f)
    df=len(o_v_f)-1
    print("Our goodness of fit for our linear function", stats.chi2.cdf(t_s,df))
    return t_s

Linear_Chi2_Generate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, `e_v_f = o_v.astype(float)` made `o_v_f`, `e_v_f` ending up the same. There was also some issue in the `for` loop. I have edited your code a bit. See what it does you are looking for:

```
from scipy import stats
import math
import random
import numpy
import scipy
import numpy as np

def Linear_Chi2_Generate(observed_values = [], expected_values = []):
    #===============================================================#
    #            !!!!!!! Generation of Data  !!!!!!!!!!             #
    #===============================================================#

    for i in range(0,12):
        a_o = random.randint(-10,10)
        b_o = random.randint(-10,10)
        y_o = a_o * (b_o + i)
        observed_values.append(y_o)

#        a_e = random.randint(-10,10)
#        b_e = random.randint(-10,10)
#        y_e = a_e * (b_e + i)
        expected_values.append(y_o + 5)


    #######################################################################################
    #                               !!! Array Setup !!!!                                  #
    #              ***Had the Array types converted to floats before computing Chi2***    #
    #                                                                                     #
    #######################################################################################
    t_s = 0
    o_v = np.array(observed_values)
    e_v = np.array(expected_values)
    o_v_f = o_v.astype(float)
    e_v_f = e_v.astype(float)
    z_o_e_v_f = zip(o_v.astype(float), e_v.astype(float))

    ######################################################################################
    for o, e in z_o_e_v_f:
        t_s += (o - e) **2 / e  # Computs the Chi2 Stat !
    ######################################################################################
    print("Observed Values ", o_v_f)
    print("Expected Values" , e_v_f)
    df=len(o_v_f)-1
    print("Our goodness of fit for our linear function", stats.chi2.cdf(t_s,df))
    return t_s

Linear_Chi2_Generate()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I ran what you suggested, and the Goodness of Fit comes out to be upon multiple runs 0.0, 1.0 and finally NaN

Comment: @Zophikel, The code itself doesn't have problem. The reason why the results vary is because the way I used to generate expected values and observed values which is randomly generating. If there was a value in expected values happening to be 0 then t_s would become inf. In order to avoid those edge cases, you can just make expected_values to be observed_values + a constant. For example, I changed the code to `expected_values.append(y_o + 10)`

Comment: Ahhh ok I understand I made note of the fact that arrays I created were basically the same,and adapted your fix to the original I wrote. I didn't expect numpy to be tricky when it comes to random number generation